# Numerical methods for finding the solution to equation

Tags: numerical-methods

Could someone show the procedure for the following two numerical method problems:

1. Solve an equation $f(x)=x^2-e^x+2=0$ with precision up to $10^{-4}$ using the secant method.
2. Using the tangent method, find one positive root of equation $\cos x=x^2-2$, with precision less than $10^{-4}.$ Localize the solution on an interval of length at least $0.5.$

Comment: Do you know about either method? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

**$1$: Find root using secant method**

$$
 f(x) = x^{2} - e^{x} + 2 $$

[image: plot]

The root is at $x= 1.3190736768573654$

---

**Secant method**

MathWorld: [Secant Method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecantMethod.html); Wikipedia: [Secant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method)

*Method*

1. Pick a value for $x_{0}$
2. Pick a value for $x_{1}$
3. Iterate using
   $$
    x_{n} = x_{n-1} - f\left(x_{n-1}\right)
   \frac{x_{n-1} - x_{n-2}}{f\left(x_{n-1}\right) - f\left(x_{n-2})\right)}
   $$

*Example*

Set $x_{0}=1$, $x_{1} = 1.5$.

$$
 \begin{align}
  x_{2} &= \color{blue}{1}.2743613145286912 \\
  x_{3} &= \color{blue}{1.31}28043183949625 \\
  x_{4} &= \color{blue}{1.319}2956677042882 \\
  x_{5} &= \color{blue}{1.31907}25774798735 \\\hline
  x_{6} &= \color{blue}{1.319073676}6646676 \\
 \end{align}
$$

---

---

**$2$: Find root using Newton's method**

$$
 f(x) = x^{2} - 2 - \cos x
$$

[image: other root]

The roots are at $x= \pm1.4546189292081113$

---

**Tangent method**

MathWorld: [Newton's Method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html), Wikipedia: [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

*Method*

1. Pick a value for $x_{0}$
2. Iterate using
   $$
    x_{n} = x_{n-1} - 
   \frac{f\left(x_{n-1}\right)}
   {f'\left(x_{n-1}\right)}
   $$

*Example*

Set $x_{0}=1$. The derivative is
$$
  f'(x)= 2x+\sin x
$$
The sequence of roots is
$$
 \begin{align}
  x_{1} &= \color{blue}{1}.5420791956361556951 \\
  x_{2} &= \color{blue}{1.45}65461937663345119 \\
  x_{3} &= \color{blue}{1.45461}99345022899466 \\
  x_{4} &= \color{blue}{1.454618929208}3852544 \\\hline
  x_{5} &= \color{blue}{1.454618929208111}2788 \\
 \end{align}
$$

Comment: how would you write your algorithm to stop at certain precision?

Comment: ok don't worry I've just realized... wouldn't hurt to hear your thoughts though.

Comment: @Anonymous: the algorithm is converging. You would stop it with an accuracy goal,  $\lvert x_{n+1} - x_{n} \rvert < 0.001$, for both cases.

Comment: yeah pretty much what I though $|x_n-x_{n-1}|< \epsilon$ although sometimes one should be careful with looping like that with floating points.

Comment: If you want more safety, check the above accuracy goal for two steps and also that the reduction in value, $f(x_n)/f(x_0)$, is large enough. Which here is not necessary.

Comment: It is reasonable to find the range og root first. for x^2-e^x+2 if x=1 then e^x=2.718.. and x^2+2=3 so we can start with x=1. For Cos x =x^2-2 if Cos x=0 we get x = 3.14../2 =1.57.. and with x^2-2=0 we get x =2^.5 =1.4142.. so it is reasonable to take x = 1.5 which is the average for start.